# WPFMVVM Set Control Focused

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

How in MVVM do you set a User Control Focus? Using Focusmanager.FocusElement={Binding ...}  Has no affect.

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type client:TelephoneNumberViewModel}">
    <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TelephoneNumber}" Width="1024" Height="540">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Margin="0 25 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  Name="textBlockQuestion"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{DynamicResource TitleTextBlock}">"What is your telephone number?"</TextBlock>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="7" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Height="460">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <wpfclient:TelephoneBox Name="TelephoneNumber"  TelephoneNumber="{Binding PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <!--<TextBox Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="40" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}"></TextBox>-->

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 40 0 0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 0 60 0" >
                        <Button Margin="0 0 0 20" Style="{DynamicResource LargeGlossyButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SurveyMobileCommand}">Mobile</Button>
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource LargeGlossyButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SurveyHomeCommand}">Home</Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button Margin="0 0 0 20"  Style="{DynamicResource LargeGlossyButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SurveyWorkCommand}">Work</Button>
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource LargeGlossyButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SurveyOtherCommand}">Other</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>



            </StackPanel>


        </Grid>



        <Grid Width="1024" Height="80" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Margin="60 0 0 20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Name="buttonContinue" 
                    Command="{Binding SurveySkipCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource LargeGlossyButtonStyle}" 
                    >Skip</Button>
        </Grid>



    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The user control does not get focus until I tab once still.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FocusManager.FocusedElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx).

**Edit after your edit**: I don't think it's possible to say without seeing your entire code, but I think this might be a focus scoping issue. You're setting the logical focus to the telephone control, but that will only have keyboard focus if that logical scope is the active one. I suspect something outside the control being templated has its own focus scope and it's not until you hit tab that the scope moves into the UserControl.

Comment: Please see my update.  The Telephone box no mater where I place the FocusManager.FocusedElement never gets focus.

Answer (score 0):

What is the context of the focus? Are they tabbing to the control, is the control receiving focus as a new item is added?

If the latter, make sure that the ListBox the DataTemplate is for has IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

Comment: The basis is when the viewmodel is loaded I want the TelephoneBox to be focused for input.  We are utilizing Prism so the ViewModel is set into a region.

Comment: You may need to look at your parent elements and if it is the parent UserCOntrol that has focus, you may want to make sure that Focusable="False" on the parent controls--not sure how Prism declares the parent. You may want to use Mole to see what is getting focus if you can't find it from your code-behind. http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/